# Drop rows from the end on condition

Tags: python, pandas

For a series

```
s = pd.Series([1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

I would like to remove all rows with consecutive zeros at the end:

```
pd.Series([1, 0, 1, 0, 2])
```

My current solution

```
s.loc[s != s.shift()]
```

does not remove the last zero row and manually drop it feels wrong. :)

Any better ideas?

Comment: just to be sure, by "*consecutive*" you don't mean that you need more than one 0 to drop it? Also you only want to remove 0s in the end or would you also want to remove then everywhere (in such case please provide additional examples)

Comment: Actually, I would like to move all zeros at the end.

Comment: OK then the first option in my answer is doing that. Your original approach was a different logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a reverse [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = s[s.ne(0)[::-1].cummax()]
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Intermediates:

```
   s  ne(0)  [::-1].cummax()
0  1   True             True
1  0  False             True
2  1   True             True
3  0  False             True
4  2   True             True
5  0  False            False
6  0  False            False
7  0  False            False
```

Another option to keep your original logic might be:

```
s[s != s.shift(-1).ffill()]
```

*Note that it doesn't keep the same indices (if you have internal stretches of duplicates), and this is not specific to 0s.*

Output:

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Slice from last nonzero value's position:

```
s[:s[s != 0].index[-1] + 1]
```

---

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`numpy.trim_zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html):

```
pd.Series(np.trim_zeros(s.values, 'b'))
```

Alternatively,

```
s[:s[::-1].ne(0).idxmax()+1]
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s.loc[s[::-1].cumsum().ne(0)]

Output:

0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    2
dtype: int64
```